# How to print text data into pdf by gopdf?

Tags: pdf, go

What I tried:

```
var data string
data = "Line1 <br>\n" +
       "Line2 \n" +
       "Line3 \n" +
       "Line4" // It's got from DB which saved by br data.

pdf.SetFont("wts11", "", 14)
pdf.SetX(100)
pdf.SetY(200)
pdf.Text(data)
```

Result:

The pdf shows:

[image]

And all other printed data disappeared.

Maybe it can't parse `<br>`.

Even change `pdf.Text(data)` to `pdf.Cell(nil, text)`, also the same result.

Ref:

> https://github.com/signintech/gopdf

Similar issue:

https://github.com/signintech/gopdf/issues/78

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not skip error handling, that's why you don't see what is the reason of failure.

Please add err check to `SetFont`, `Text`, `WritePdf` functions. In my case I found that error was coming from `SetFont` since it was not found.

This code works well if you have `open-sans.ttf` in your working dir:

```
package main

import (
    "log"

    "github.com/signintech/gopdf"
)

func main() {
    pdf := gopdf.GoPdf{}
    pdf.Start(gopdf.Config{PageSize: *gopdf.PageSizeA4})
    pdf.AddPage()

    if err := pdf.AddTTFFont("open-sans", "open-sans.ttf"); err != nil {
        log.Print(err.Error())
        return
    }

    if err := pdf.SetFont("open-sans", "", 14); err != nil {
        log.Print(err.Error())
        return
    }

    pdf.SetX(100)
    pdf.SetY(200)

    data := "Line1 <br/>\n" +
        "Line2 \n" +
        "Line3 \n" +
        "Line4"

    if err := pdf.Text(data); err != nil {
        log.Print(err.Error())
        return
    }

    if err := pdf.WritePdf("hello.pdf"); err != nil {
        log.Print(err.Error())
        return
    }
}
```